# checking phone number exist in the contact list in android

Tags: android, android-intent

i m trying to check the number exist in the contact list, i use the below code but i always getting error at this line

```
 Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
```

can anyone help me to find out the problem, i had given the permission to read my contact in manifest

```
  public String getContactName(String number)
{
    String name = null;
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try 
    {
       if (cur.moveToFirst())
       {
           name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
           return name;
       }
    }
    finally 
    {
    if (cur != null)
       cur.close();
    }
    return "unknown number";
}
```

this is my error log! [image: error log]

Comment: and which kind of error?

Comment: @Sajmon check my error log

Comment: your `this.getContentResolver()` is assigned to null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:(use context)

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    /// number is the phone number
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (cur != null){
            cur.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I find a contact by _ID?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Handled NullPointerException.

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    if (number != null) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor curContacts = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (curContacts.moveToNext()) {
            String contactNumber = curContacts.getString(curContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (number.equals(contactNumber)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```